# Algorithms for key value pair, where key is string

Tags: database, algorithm, search, indexing, inverted-index

I have a problem where there is a huge list of strings or phrases it might scale from 100,000 to 100Million. when i search for a phrase if found it gives me the Id or index to database for further operation. I know hash table can be used for this, but i am looking for other algorithm which could serve me to generate index based on strings and can also be useful in some other features like autocomplete etc.

I read suffix tree/array based on some SO threads they serve the purpose but consumes alot memory than i can afford. Any alternatives to this?

Since my search is only in a huge list of millions of strings. No docs no webpages not interested in search engine like lucene etc.

Also read about inverted index sounds helpful but which algorithm i need to study for it?.

Comment: When you say, "useful in some other features", what do you have in mind besides autocomplete?

Comment: I would think that a regular trie would be better for autocomplete since at any node in the tree, its subtree gives all known completions for the prefix.

Answer (score 1):

If this Database index is within MS SQL Server you may get good results with SQL Full Text Indexing.  Other SQL providers may have a similar function but I would not be able to help with those.

Check out: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx